# Laravel 5.7 user verification email not sending at registrations time

Tags: laravel

I just upgraded from 5.6 to 5.7 and followed the instructions precisely.  When registration happens, the email is not sending immediately.  However, it works when clicking on the the message to resend it.  Is it actually a feature to send the email at the point of registration? or Do I need to manually add a function.

Comment: What exact version of Laravel does have this bug? Please.

Comment: You are right! It is good to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the source, it seems it doesn't get dispatched upon registration automatically. However, you can easily change that behavior.

In `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController`, your `create()` method should look like this. This should work, assuming that you have followed all the other steps documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification).

```
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Route [verification.verify] not defined.

Comment: ok, I added Auth::routes(['verify' => true]), now problem `Route [verification.verify] not defined.` is gone, verification email is passed, but the new user is getting logged in without prompt for verifying email.

Comment: Thanks Mozammil, this solution should be a pull request for Laravel :), simple and slick and is expected behavior for new signups.

Comment: It cannot be a pull request, it is not a part of laravel, it is a part of your project.